# Ошибка nginx emerg ssl_ctx_load_verify_locations

Tags: nginx

Мой /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:

```
server {
    root /var/www/html;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name somesite.ru;

    location = / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location /  {
        try_files $uri /test/$uri /test/index.html;
    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/somesite.ru/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/somesite.ru/privkey.pem;
    ssl_client_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/somesite.ru/ca2.crt;
    ssl_verify_client on;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
}

server {
    if ($host = somesite.ru) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name somesite.ru;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Когда я выполняю `"nginx -t"`, я получаю ошибку:

> nginx: [emerg]
>   SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations("/etc/letsencrypt/live/omp.kolebor.ru/ca2.crt") failed (SSL:)

Я несколько раз проверял путь до сертификата, и он верен.

Я пытался найти решения этой проблемы, и в других источниках обычно писалось более детально описание ошибки в скобках, где у меня просто (SSL:). Поэтому я даже не могу понять, в чём может быть проблема.

Может ли возникать это ошибка из-за невалидного ca2.crt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело оказалось все-таки в сертификате. Я создал новый через openssl и с ним всё стало работать.